# Shortcuts to other videos on YouTube

Tags: youtube

On YouTube, when the person in the video has another video as a reference to show, in the upper corner is shown a link that directs what they want to show.

This is a example:

[image]

I have some videos that I would like to do, but I do not know where to do it on YouTube.

Does anyone know the name of this and how can I add it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in:
Creator studio => Video Manager => (Select Video) => Card (or "End screen & Annotations")

There you select time and click on "Add element" button. Now you can choose, what you want to add.
[image]